# C++: Want to make an easy nested struct

Tags: c++, struct

I'm a C++ beginner and trying to make a nested struct which has 2 sub-structs under it.
The code is:

```
struct Sub_number{
    int one;
    int two;
};

struct Sub_size{
    int width;
    int height;
};

struct MainStruct{
    struct Sub_number number;
    struct Sub_size size;
}main;
```

and I got ***[Cannot use dot operator on a type]*** error from Xcode when I tried to put a value in it like this:

```
main.number.one = 13;
    ^
```

Does anyone has any ideas what's wrong with this code...?

---

Thank you so so much everyone. As you wrote, the name I've using was the no-good point!! Silly me.. I'll double check when I'm going to ask on StackOverflow next time.

Thanks!

Comment: This won't necessarily fix the error, but you don't need to say "`struct`" inside of `MainStruct`, and you shouldn't be calling anything other than the `main` function `main`. See this "working" example: http://ideone.com/IOqMJ1

Comment: Also, you aren't using "nested structs" here. You simply have a struct whose data members are user defined types (your first two structs.) Nested types are when you define types inside of other types.

Comment: You need to put `mainStruct.number.one` inside a function. You cannot have non-declaration statements outside of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`main` is the reserved word for main function (starting point of application) you need to change the variable name to something else . This will fix the issue

```
struct Sub_number {
    int one;
    int two;
};

struct Sub_size {
    int width;
    int height;
};

struct MainStruct {
    struct Sub_number number;
    struct Sub_size size;
}someVariable;

void main() {
  someVariable.number.one = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your struct name can't be `main` .main is a unique function name `int main()`.change the struct name to others!